# Match by id and date between 2 tables, OR last known match id

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to make work following:

- `T1`: Take `id per dt` where `name = A` which is `most recent by load_id`

  - Notice 2 records on 5-Jan-23, with load_id 2 and 3 => take load_id = 3
- `T2`: And display corresponding `id per dt for each param` rows, with most recent `load_id`

  - Notice only load_id = 13 is kept on 05-Jan-23
- `T2`: In case of date now available in `T1`, keep `T2` rows matching last known `id`

[image]

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/-JO16GSj

My SQL seems a bit wild. Can it be simplified?

```
SELECT t2.dt, t2.param, t2.load_id, t2.id FROM
(SELECT 
  dt, 
  param,
  load_id,
  MAX(load_id) OVER (PARTITION BY dt, param) AS max_load_id,
  id
FROM table2) t2

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM
(SELECT
  dt, 
  id,
  load_id,
  MAX(load_id) OVER (PARTITION BY dt) AS max_load_id
FROM table1
WHERE name = 'A') t1_prep
WHERE t1_prep.load_id = t1_prep.max_load_id) t1

ON t1.dt = t2.dt and t1.id = t2.id
  
WHERE t2.load_id = t2.max_load_id

ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query can be rewritten as:

```sql
SELECT t2.*
FROM   ( SELECT *
         FROM   table2
         ORDER BY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY dt, param ORDER BY load_id DESC)
         FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
       ) t2
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       ( SELECT *
         FROM   table1
         WHERE  name = 'A'
         ORDER BY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY dt ORDER BY load_id DESC)
         FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
       ) t1
       ON t1.dt = t2.dt and t1.id = t2.id
ORDER BY t2.dt, t2.param
```

However, since the columns from `t1` are never output and are joined with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (and will only output single rows per `dt`) then it is irrelevant whether a match is found or not with `t1` and that table can be eliminated from the query simplifying it to:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT *
  FROM   table2
  ORDER BY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY dt, param ORDER BY load_id DESC)
  FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES
)
ORDER BY dt, param;
```

or using your query:

```sql
SELECT dt, param, load_id, id
FROM   (
  SELECT dt, param, load_id, id,
         MAX(load_id) OVER (PARTITION BY dt, param) AS max_load_id
  FROM   table2
)
WHERE  load_id = max_load_id
ORDER BY dt, param
```

Which, for the sample data, all output:

| DT | PARAM | LOAD_ID | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 04-JAN-23 | 0 | 11 | 1 |
| 04-JAN-23 | 1 | 11 | 1 |
| 05-JAN-23 | 0 | 13 | 3 |
| 05-JAN-23 | 1 | 13 | 3 |
| 06-JAN-23 | 0 | 14 | 3 |
| 06-JAN-23 | 1 | 14 | 3 |
| 07-JAN-23 | 1 | 14 | 3 |
| 08-JAN-23 | 1 | 15 | 3 |
| 09-JAN-23 | 0 | 16 | 3 |
| 09-JAN-23 | 1 | 16 | 3 |
| 10-JAN-23 | 0 | 17 | 3 |
| 10-JAN-23 | 1 | 17 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YnM32J36)

Comment: There seems a difference in the last column `ÌD`. It is not clear what `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES` does.

Comment: @aeiou Missed `DESC` on one of the `ORDER BY` clauses, it should work now. `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES` does exactly what it says and only fetches the first row and any other rows that are tied with it (from ordering of the `ORDER BY` clause).